# can't we define variable that contain class that variable inside of?

Tags: java

Code is below:

```
public class Final {

    int x;

    Final(int i)
    {
        x = i;
    }

    protected void finalize()
    {
        System.out.println("Final of the class!" + this.x);
    }

    public void generate(int count)
    {
        Final final = new Final(count);
    }

}
```

Look at the `Final final = new Final(count);` I get error from this line. (`not a statement ; excepted`). Can't we define variable that contain class that variable inside of?

Comment: Why are you declaring a variable with the name 'final'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`final` is a keyword.

java will interpret it as:

```
[type] [modifier]=new [type]()
```

This lacks a variable name and is invalid.

From the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3):

> FieldDeclaration:
>       FieldModifiers<sub>[opt]</sub> Type VariableDeclarators ;

We take `final` to be a FieldModifier. We now need a type and a declarator. This is inconsistent with what was given by you, which was parsed as `Type FieldModifiers`. The parsing does not result in a valid expression.

Also as per JLS section 3.9 `final` is a keyword and may not be an identifier, even where it would be unambiguous.

Comment: Ok, but I suppose finalize() function doesn't run? what can reason be?

Comment: @Yusuf Did you first fix the variable name? `finalize(` has special meaning.

Comment: It makes no sense to say how that line will be interpreted. It is invalid according to JLS §3.9.

Comment: @arshajii I stated how it was parsed. I then state how the parsed data does not fit a valid pattern and cannot be used. It is still determined by the compiler to be of that pattern.

Comment: @hexafraction is finalize destructor of class?

Comment: @Yusuf There's no such thing as a true destructor. The JVM's garbage collector will call `finalize(` before destroying an object with no strong references remaining.

Comment: @hexafraction GC **may** call , depends on the JVM implementation !

Comment: @TheNewIdiot Yes. My bad. OP: ***Never, ever, ever*** rely on `finalize`. No guarantees may be made, and it's a bad idea in all respects.

Answer (score 6):

`final` is a [keyword](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html), meaning you can't use it as a variable name as per [JLS §3.9](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.9).

So all you need to do is change the name:

```
Final myFinal = new Final(count);
```

Answer (score 4):

`final` is a [keyword](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.9) , cannot be used as an identifier.

[JLS §3.9.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8):

> An identifier cannot have the same spelling (Unicode character sequence) as a keyword (§3.9), boolean literal (§3.10.3), or the null literal (§3.10.7), or a compile-time error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem stems from your last method is using final as your variable name

```
public void generate(int count)
{
    Final final = new Final(count);
}
```

now that is not a problem except when it is lower case making it the keyword final which IS the problem since final makes a varible unchangable once made. The best way to avoid this is to avoid keywords or making them all capitalized to tell the complier that this is NOT a keyword.